# Similarity- find the sides marked with letters

Tags: geometry

[image: marked]

a= 2 1/2 e= 3 according to book

my work ended up with 2/11 as following:
[image]

Comment: Where did the $x$ come from?

Comment: unknown sides a and e

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unknowns are $a$ and $e$. You do not need to introduce another variable (e.g., $x$ in your working) to calculate $a$ and $e$.

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{EF}{DC} &= \dfrac{DF}{AC}\implies\dfrac{6}{e} = \dfrac{4}{2}\implies e = \dfrac{2 \times 6}{4} = 3\\\dfrac{ED}{BA} &= \dfrac{DF}{AC}\implies\dfrac{5}{a} = \dfrac{4}{2}\implies a =\dfrac{5 \times 2}{4} = \dfrac{5}{2} = 2\dfrac{1}{2}\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks , sorry for the stupid question lol